# Where does the string in ExpectedException.NoExceptionMessage appear?

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, unit-testing

I am doing some unit testing in Visual studio:

```
/// <summary>
/// Padding14 should throw an ArgumentOutOfRangeException if string is longer than 14
/// </summary>
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentOutOfRangeException), "Missing ArgumentOutOfRange exception when argument too long")]
public void TestPadding14_ArgTooLong()
{
    string input = "abcdefghijklmnop"; 
    input.Padding14();

}
```

This line tests the function:

```
public static string Padding14(this string input)
{
    if (input == "")
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("StringExtensions.Padding14: Input string empty");
    }
    if (input.Length > 14)
    {
        //throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("stringExtenstions.Padding14: Input string too long");
    }
    //throw new NotImplementedException();
    return null;
}
```

Expected outcome: The test should fail, and the information about the failure should include the string "Missing ArgumentOutOfRange exception when argument too long", because the exception in the tested function is commented out.

The test is working as expected, but i cannot find the string i put in the second argument of ExpectedException anywhere. Not in the test explorer window, not in the output -> Tests window.

So where is it supposed to go, and what could cause it not to appear there? This applies to both Visual studio 2015 and 2017, community edition.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at documentation of [ExpectedExceptionBaseAttribute.NoExceptionMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.expectedexceptionbaseattribute.noexceptionmessage.aspx), the following is written:

> *This API supports the product infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.*

However, in the remarks following is written:

> *If the test fails because an exception was not thrown, this message is included in the test result.*

Conclusion:

You will see it in the test result but **only** if it failed.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond to my question. I had already understood what you said. 
The problem I am having is that the test does fail, but does not include the message in the test results.